# Update Excel Cell using OLEDB

Tags: excel, oledb

I want to update 1 cell in an Excel (xlsx) file using OLEDB.
I have attached my code.
The first time you run, it fills in the values because INSERT is working.
The second time you run, it APPENDS the values because the UPDATE fails, and my Catch performs an INSERT.  My goal is to have the UPDATE command work.  When the UPDATE command executes, I get an error message:

No value given for one or more required parameters.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.InsertCSVIntoSheet(String excelPath, String sheet, String csvPath) in C:\Users\jbendler.atlab\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 175

This code comes from a demo Console App.  This is the program.cs file.
The main part of the code is located at the bottom of the InsertCSVIntoSheet method.  The output xlsx file is simply a new workbook, unedited. The input file is simply a text file, named with a .csv extension, that contains the following separated by carriage-return/linefeed - so the file has 5 lines with one character per line:

A

B

C

D

E

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InsertCSVIntoSheet(@"c:\temp\book1.xlsx", "NewSheet", @"c:\temp\test.csv");
    }

    private static void InsertCSVIntoSheet(string excelPath, string sheet, string csvPath)
    {
        int column;
        int row;
        int pos;
        bool done;
        char readUntilChar;
        string csvData;
        string columnName;
        string cell;
        string excelSheetName;
        List<Tuple<int, int, object>> values = new List<Tuple<int, int, object>>();
        string connectionString = CreateOleDbConnectionStringForExcel(excelPath);
        OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        decimal decimalTest;
        DateTime dateTimeTest;
        int status;
        int numColumns;

        // Put CSV in to row/column/value Tuples
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvPath))
        {
            csvData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            row = 1;

            // Split the csv data by new line
            foreach (string line in csvData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    column = 1;
                    pos = 0;
                    cell = string.Empty;

                    // Split each line by ',' to get each cell.  A value wrapped in '"' can include a ','
                    while (pos < line.Length)
                    {
                        cell = string.Empty;

                        // Check the first character.  If it is a '"' then we assume the cell is surrounded
                        //   in '"' and do NOT include the '"' in the output to the excel cell.
                        if (line[pos] == '"')
                        {
                            readUntilChar = '"';
                            pos++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            readUntilChar = ',';
                        }

                        done = line[pos] == readUntilChar;

                        if (line[pos] == '"')
                        {
                            // Skip over second '"' for a blank ("")
                            pos++;
                        }

                        while (!done)
                        {
                            cell += line[pos++];

                            if (pos == line.Length || line[pos] == readUntilChar)
                            {
                                if (readUntilChar == '"')
                                {
                                    // Skip the '"'
                                    pos++;
                                }

                                done = true;
                            }
                        }

                        // Skip over the ','
                        pos++;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell))
                        {
                            // Test the data to determine the type (check for decimal and DateTime).
                            if (decimal.TryParse(cell, out decimalTest))
                            {
                                values.Add(new Tuple<int, int, object>(row, column, decimalTest));
                            }
                            else if (DateTime.TryParse(cell, out dateTimeTest))
                            {
                                values.Add(new Tuple<int, int, object>(row, column, dateTimeTest));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Write out the value as a string
                                values.Add(new Tuple<int, int, object>(row, column, cell));
                            }
                        }

                        column++;
                    }
                }

                row++;
            }
        }

        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            excelSheetName = GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString).Where(n => n.ToUpper().StartsWith(sheet.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault();

            //Set the connection string to recognize the header and to operate in Update mode(IMEX= 0)
            using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString.Replace("IMEX=1", "IMEX=0")))
            {
                oleDbConnection.Open();

                oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;
                oleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                if (excelSheetName != null)
                {
                    // Delete Sheet
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText = "DROP TABLE [" + sheet + "]";
                    status = oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    excelSheetName = sheet + "$";
                }

                numColumns = values.Max(v => v.Item2);

                oleDbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [" + sheet + "](";

                for (int index = 0; index < numColumns; index++)
                {
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText += "Column" + index.ToString() + " CHAR(255), ";
                }

                oleDbCommand.CommandText = oleDbCommand.CommandText.Substring(0, oleDbCommand.CommandText.Length - 2) + ")";

                status = oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString.Replace("IMEX=1", "IMEX=0")))
            {
                oleDbConnection.Open();
                oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;

                // Write out new values
                foreach (Tuple<int, int, object> tuple in values)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        columnName = GetExcelColumnName(tuple.Item2) + (tuple.Item1 + 1).ToString();

                        oleDbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + excelSheetName + columnName + ":" + columnName + "] SET " + "F1" + " = '" + tuple.Item3.ToString() + "'";
                        status = oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (OleDbException oledbex)
                    {
                        oleDbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + excelSheetName + "] VALUES ('" + tuple.Item3.ToString() + "')";
                        status = oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
    {
        OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = null;
        DataTable dataTable = null;
        List<string> excelSheetNames = null;

        using (oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oleDbConnection.Open();
            dataTable = oleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        }

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            excelSheetNames = new List<string>(dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().EndsWith("$") || r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().EndsWith("$'")).Select(r => r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().ToUpper()));
        }

        return excelSheetNames;
    }

    private static string CreateOleDbConnectionStringForExcel(string sourceFile)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceFile);

        switch (fileInfo.Extension.ToUpper())
        {

            case ".XLS":
                return string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'", sourceFile);
            case ".XLSX":
            case ".XLSM":
                return string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'", sourceFile);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException("File type not supported.");
        }
    }

    private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
    {
        string columnName = String.Empty;
        int dividend = columnNumber;
        int modulo;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
            dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
        }

        return columnName;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  You state what you want to do, and provide some code. What are you asking for help with?

Comment: There's no WHERE in your update SQL.  Are you trying to update the whole sheet?  That seems at odds with your fallback being an insert.  What's the error message when the update fails?

Comment: The goal and error message have been added.

Comment: Hi Tim - when you update the spreadsheet - the where is implied in the table argument by using a range.

Comment: When you assign `oleDbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE...` could you please post the complete contents of the `CommandText` property after the actual assignment but before the `ExecuteNonQuery` is called?